# Ubuntu SDHCI Error

Tags: lubuntu, emmc

I am using a laptop with just an eMMC as the storage. I am using Lubuntu 17.04

For some time my `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` have been being spammed with:

```
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585456] mmc0: Got data interrupt 0x00000002 even though no data operation was in progress.
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585479] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585492] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585511] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585520] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585530] sdhci: Present:  0x1fff0000 | Host ctl: 0x00000035
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585539] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000b | Blk gap:  0x00000080
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585547] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585557] sdhci: Timeout:  0x00000005 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585567] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff000b | Sig enab: 0x02ff000b
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585575] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585585] sdhci: Caps:     0x446cc8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00000807
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585594] sdhci: Cmd:      0x00000c1a | Max curr: 0x00000000
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585603] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000008b
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585612] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x35400208
Jun 27 09:08:31 my-laptop kernel: [   96.585617] sdhci: ===========================================
```

It runs out of the disk space very rapidly.

Here is an excerpt from the lshw:

```
 description: Notebook
 product: 80M1 (LENOVO_MT_80M1_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo Yoga 300-11IBR)
 vendor: LENOVO
 version: Lenovo Yoga 300-11IBR
 serial: P200QHGF
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=IDEAPAD frontpane

     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: C7CN29WW
          date: 06/15/2016
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 3008KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb zipboot biosbootspecification netboot uefi

        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 35
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:91200000-912fffff
           *-generic
                description: SD Host controller
                product: SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
                vendor: O2 Micro, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:91201000-91201fff memory:9
```

It seems to have been a common issue in the past, but I couldn't find anything useful/recent.

Please let me know if you need more information to suggest a solution

Comment: What model is this? Is it one with a Bay Trail/Cherry Trail processor.

Comment: Here is the processor details:

`     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CHV
          size: 2559MHz
          capacity: 2560MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 83MHz
 
`

Comment: I looked up the porcessor info on http://ark.intel.com/products/91830/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3710-2M-Cache-up-to-2_56-GHz which shows that it is braswell.

Comment: Is there any specific driver or something that I need to install for (L)Ubuntu to et this fixed?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up. Replaced Lubuntu with Ubuntu and the problem is gone. The only price I am paying is, with a couple of Chrome windows, thunderbird and a commandline I am always running close to 4G (and my laptop has got only 4G RAM). I can live with it.